# In what kind of Banach algebras is 0 the only topological zero divisor?

Tags: functional-analysis, recreational-mathematics, banach-algebras

On page 33 of http://math.aalto.fi/opetus/harmanal/pruju/calg04.pdf it is asked
in what kind of Banach algebras is 0 the only topological zero divisor.

What do they mean by kind of Banach algebras. Using part (b) of the exercise it
follows that the Banach algebras may not have invertible elements. Is
this a kind of Banach Algebras?

Comment: It should be clear that if $A=\mathbb{C}$, then 0 is the only topological zero divisor. Try to prove that if $A\neq\mathbb{C}$, then there is a non zero, non-invertible element that is a limit point of Inv(A) (the group of invertible elements) and hence is a topological zero divisor.

Answer (score 2):

Writing $G(A)$ to be the open subset of invertible elements, any $x \in \partial G(A)$ (the boundary) is a topological zero divisor.
To see this, just observe that $\frac{xx_n^{-1}}{\|x_n^{-1}\|}\to 0$ whenever $x_n\in G(A)$ converges to $x$.

If $A$ has no nonzero topological zero divisors then, by the above, $\{0\}\cup G(A)$ is closed and so the set of nonzero non invertible elements, call it $S(A)$, is open.
Further, if $x \in S(A)$, then the continuous function $f(\lambda)= (1-\lambda)x + \lambda e$ on $[0,1]$ has image in $S(A) \cup G(A)$, the union of two disjoint open sets. Contradiction. So the assumption that $S(A) \neq \emptyset$ was wrong.

Hence $A = \mathbb{C}$ by the Gelfand-Mazur theorem.

Comment: Excellent answer. (+1). I would just add another line to justify your argument. If we define $\lambda_o=\sup \{ \lambda \: | \: f(\lambda)\in S(A)\}$, then it is clear to see by the definition of supremum that $f(\lambda_o)\in \partial G(A)=\{0\}$ This implies $x$ is invertible as $0<\lambda_o<1$ by openness of $G(A)$ and $S(A)$, which is really absurd as you remarked.